# How to make the entire "box-part" of a navbar link highlight using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My second question here. 
I was able to make this work using CSS without flexbox.

[image]

I pasted the code for above here:

https://codepen.io/kkpm/pen/MWgdOZE

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: maroon;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#links {
  float: right;
  line-height: 60px;
}
#links li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#links li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#links li a:hover {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
}
```

HTML below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <div id="logo"><img src="flag.JPG" alt="" height="60px" /></div>
      <div id="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="welcome">Hi!</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem with the above code is that I eyeballed things by adjusting the px. I want to center the `<li>` text vertically at all times *while* having the blue box area around it fill up, for lack of a better term to describe it, the cell no matter what.

How do I get the same result using flexbox (or any other method) ***without using javascript*** to format the `<ul>/<li>` elements?

It's driving me crazy trying to do this. I searched Google thoroughly. I am having a difficult time, however, because my understanding of the flexbox is weak.

Some things I've tried:

1. I set padding and margin to 0px for `*`
2. I set box-sizing to `border-box` for HTML
3. I set `nav` to 60px
   then I tried to set `nav li` to
   `display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;`
4. for the logo div I put it as position fixed and `justify-content: flex-start`
5. I read this site trying to format this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The problem is I can't get the links to the center and the blue-highlighted section to highlight as it should. I'm very confused with flexbox and if someone could please guide me step by step his/her thought process as to how to get below result using flexbox, I would truly appreciate it. I will study your answer over and over again until I master how to create this fixed navigation bar.

Comment: The blue highlight occurs when I'm hovering over it with a mouse. My goal is to learn how to make that happen for a navbar using CSS-Flexbox regardless of what the height of the navbar is or what the size is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` and then apply `align-items: center;` to get elements vertically centred. This would be rather a cleaner approach over using `floats`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  background-color: maroon;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

#logo img {
  max-height: 30px;
}

#links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

#links li:hover {
  background: blue;
}

#links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
      alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<section id="welcome">Hi!</section>
```

Comment: I only have one more question.

1) flex-grow

You set the #logo flex-grow property to 1. When I set it to 0 or erase it the navbar moves left. What does this property do? The MDN guide is confusing:

"It specifies how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item (the flex grow factor)."

Could you use more simple English to explain why you used it? Or why this is here?  Did you put this to "push" the rest of the contents to the right? What does this property, exactly, do? Why did you put this here? What does it do?

Comment: Actually, this question is not answered in full. Everything is amazing, except I can't figure out how to have the entire blue area highlighted when I hover over it like I posted in the original picture. Could you please help me achieve that result?

Comment: I did this, but I don't like my solution. I don't want the box to move when I hover over it. I want the cell-area to be highlighted blue without the box moving  (my solution)   =>        .#links li a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

Comment: alright, flex-grow is simple terms defines the precedence of which element should occupy more space. If all elements have the same value for flex-grow, then space is divided equally. I'll update the code for the selection

Comment: Wow! It works. What did you change to get the entire blue part highlighted?

Comment: just added padding to `li` instead of `nav`. If the padding is for `nav`, it would be hard to get full blue

Comment: Sir thank you. Sorry to bother you, but how would I make the blue area (when highlighted) more or less equal to the left and the right? I had to adjust #links li { to   padding: 1em 0.4em 1em 2.6em; but is there a better way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200112/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-d234kdsafjk).